# Not able to write NSDictionary to plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, plist

Update: I am able to write tot he file when I change the following line

```
[infoDict setObject:userList forKey:@"users"];
```

to

```
[infoDict setObject:@"sampleString" forKey:@"users"];
```

so, there must be problem with the structure I'm trying to write to the file, any thoughts?

---

I am trying to create a plist file and write to it at runtime in my iOS app. I am not able to write to it but I'm able to read though. The writeToFile method returns a 'NO'.
When I manually try to manually open the file I created using Finder, it says "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", which I understand because on opening the file using a text editor it is empty and doesn't show any xml tags which a file of type plist should have.
And I know I can read from it because on manually dragging a 'valid' plist file in the folder, my code is able to read an empty list from there.

1) Why isn't it creating a valid plist file?

and,

2) Why am I not able to write to (even a valid) plist file?

```
    NSLog(@"* Writing contents to plist file *");

    NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* plistPath = nil;

    if ((plistPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.plist"]))
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSLog(exists ? @"yes, file exists": @"no, file doesnt exist");

        if (!exists) {
            NSLog(@"creating file since it doesnt exist");
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:plistPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        }

        NSLog(@"path of file: %@", plistPath);
        NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"infoDict: %@", infoDict);

        [infoDict setObject:userList forKey:@"users"];
        NSLog(@"infoDict: %@", infoDict);

        BOOL wrote = [infoDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(wrote ? @"yes, wrote to the file": @"no, didn't write to file");
   }
    NSLog(@"--------------------------------------------");
```

Following is the output in the console:

```
    2014-10-17 10:50:11.290 UserReggy[1228:10032] * Writing contents to plist file *
2014-10-17 10:50:11.291 UserReggy[1228:10032] yes, file exists
2014-10-17 10:50:11.291 UserReggy[1228:10032] path of file: /Users/rvyas1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DB612284-F481-467A-BAE8-37750497F42A/data/Containers/Data/Application/C9620C4D-EF1F-4C17-8D28-4E9B3B41F2C2/Documents/users.plist
2014-10-17 10:50:11.291 UserReggy[1228:10032] infoDict: {
}
2014-10-17 10:50:11.291 UserReggy[1228:10032] infoDict: {
    users =     {
        dfgdfgd = "<User: 0x7ffd884da820>";
    };
}
2014-10-17 10:50:11.292 UserReggy[1228:10032] no, didn't write to file
2014-10-17 10:50:11.294 UserReggy[1228:10032] --------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check your data in userList , it must be property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) , doc in [the NSMutableDictionary Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:)

Comment: userList is an NSMutableDictionary which I think is a suitable object to write in the plistFile according to the reference link you posted. Even when I put it in a NSDictionary and then try to write it in a file, it's not working.

Comment: May be the path ,you do not have the permission to the file or in the path.Every file in your app, may affected by the file system defined.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in line         `NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];`

it will give you null object beacause your `plistPath` is nil

Comment: The plistPath isn't nil after the if statement (assignment) anymore, I'm also NSLog-ing it in the console if you look there.

Comment: certainly, your infoDict is null you can't set value for it try alloc it if null

Comment: @HuyNghia Thanks! You're right, I WAS making infoDict null, but now I've removed the line : NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; and replaced it with : NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  now it's an empty dictionary rather than null. But the writing problem remains, it's still returning a no.

Comment: @justintime are you sure your file already create try BOOL Success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil]; to check

Comment: @Huy Nghia  I checked using the finder too, it's getting created.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *fileData;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        fileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        if ([fileData initWithContentsOfFile: path])
        {
            fileData = [fileData initWithContentsOfFile: path];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];

        fileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    }

        [fileData setObject:data forKey:qid];

    BOOL wrote = [fileData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    NSLog(wrote ? @"yes, wrote to the file": @"no, didn't write to file");
```

Try this. Worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, your code didn't work for me, same output.. But can you elaborate on what you think is different in your code, they look the same to me..

Comment: @justintime You are missing the line `fileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` or `fileData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];`. Seems like your Dictionary object is not being allocated at all, hence giving you null value at all times.

Comment: Yes, I corrected that. Sorry, I'll update the code above. But, I still can't write to the file.

Comment: My value for the path is **/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7C881490-C50B-4B11-B9C3-8C2AF02B5A5D/data/Applications/365D6D67-38EE-4DFB-8129-CF1A5B7E34C6/Documents/data.plist** . I note you have an extra **/Containers/Data** in your path. Maybe this is the reason you are facing this.