# Alternative NSUserDedaults. Xcode. iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, caching, nsuserdefaults

Now I save the cache in `NSUserDefaults`. As before, I used the small array, the `NSUserDefaults` for me. Now when you save large array in `NSUserDefaults` application freeze. What are the alternatives to the cache arrays in objective - c for iOS?

**UPDATE:**
I want to save 30-60 HTML file into an array. and then the array cache. Stores an array to NSUserDefaults long. that is better for me to use? the database? nscache? if a database, what?

Comment: NSUserDefaults are used to cache small data if you have large data then i suggest you to go through database

Comment: Depending on how much data you want to cache the goto is usually Core Data to provide an "offline" version of the app. Core Data is not worth the work though if you only need to cache a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the HTML data as **NSString** into a **NSDictionary** and save it in a **.plist** file in the **documents directory**. You would be able to edit, append and delete your data as you want using this approach.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Here is another [question I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26401334/3332367). You might want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a caching pupose,you can use NSCache and iOS manages the memory.But its not guaranteed the availability of data always.iOS may remove data and free up the memory because of memory warning.
       If your data is higher in size,you should save the data to document directory instead of directly saving to RAM (Saving to Objects use RAM memory).Write data to a file or use plist.

Comment: NSCache helped me! Thank you! But I still do not understand what is the difference between NSUserDefaults and NSCache? Why do I need if NSUserDefaults esit NSCache?

Comment: In case of any memory warning received,OS will remove datas in NSCache but not from NSUserDefault.So you need to check the object existence in NSCache before using it.

Comment: NSCache to freeze app, because I write a large array